# Error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers what does this mean?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have something like this. I am having difficulty understanding this error.
Why does accessing `filterController` here give this error here, but it doesn't give this error if I move the current entire `TextFormField` creation (between comments A and B) inside the build method? How does moving the entire `TextFormField` inside the build method make `filterController` static then and resolve this issue?

```
class AppHomeState extends State<AppHome> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
{

    TabController _tabController;
    final filterController = new TextEditingController(text: "Search");
        //----A
        TextFormField email = new TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        controller: filterController,    ------>ERROR : Error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers
        );
       //----B

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        return new Scaffold(
                appBar: new AppBar(..),
        );
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I think we need a bit more context (haha) for this question to answer it properly. The important part is where you've defined this chunk of code.

From the error you've described (`Error : Only static members can be accessed in initializers`), it's in the constructor of the class. In flutter you shouldn't really be building anything in the constructor. So if you could post your entire class, that would definitely help us help you!

Comment: Glad his answer helps, but I don't think it is a particularly correct answer in that it doesn't address the cause of the problem or steer you away from making it again. If you simply replace the variable in place with a call to the function I'd expect you to get the same error. If he edited to suggest that you then call the function he's defined in the build function rather than in the constructor as it appears you might be doing, then I would consider it a more correct answer...

Comment: ill try this out shortly

Comment: @rmtmckenzie after going through this looks like this is not what I was looking for as it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Okay. Please edit your question to include your entire class. Then I or someone else will be in a better position to help you.

Comment: Ill update the code

Comment: I just updated the code and the question

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
class AppHomeState extends State<AppHome> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

    TabController _tabController;
    final filterController = new TextEditingController(text: "Search");
    TextFormField email = ...
```

`...` is an initializer and there is no way to access `this` at this point.
Initializers are executed before the constructor, but `this` is only allowed to be accessed after the call to the super constructor (implicit in your example) was completed.
Therefore only in the constructor body (or later) access to `this` is allowed.

This is why you get the error message:

```
controller: filterController,
```

accesses `this.filterController` (`this` is implicit if you don't write it explicit).

To work around your issue (assuming `email` needs to be `final`) you can use a factory constructor and a constructor initializer list:

```
class AppHomeState extends State<AppHome> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  factory SingleTickerProviderStateMixin() => 
      new SingleTickerProviderStateMixin._(new TextEditingController(text: "Search"));

  SingleTickerProviderStateMixin._(TextEditingController textEditingController) : 
      this.filterController = textEditingController,   
      this.email = new TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        controller: textEditingController);

  TabController _tabController;
  final filterController;
  final TextFormField email;
```

or when the `email` field does not need to be final `email` can be initialized in the constructor initializer list:

```
class AppHomeState extends State<AppHome> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  SingleTickerProviderStateMixin() {
    email = new TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        controller: filterController,
    );
  }

  TabController _tabController;
  final filterController = new TextEditingController(text: "Search");
  TextFormField email;
```

but in Flutter widgets `initState` is usually used for that

```
class AppHomeState extends State<AppHome> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    email = new TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        controller: filterController,
    );
  }

  TabController _tabController;
  final filterController = new TextEditingController(text: "Search");
  TextFormField email;
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this now it definitely makes sense.

Answer (score 10):

You can keep that as a method:

```
Widget getEmailController(){
return new TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        controller: filterController,
        );
}
```

and use it in UI:

```
body: Container(
child: getEmailController();
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this variable to a function and you can take context in this function parameters.

Example

```
Widget myDialog (BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: new Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("Invalid Username/Password"),
          new Text("Please verify your login credentials"),
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("Ok"),
            onPressed:() {
              Navigator.pop(context);//Error : Only static members can be accessed in initializers
            }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  );
}

// Using if you are doing in a class
this.myDialog(context);

// Using if you are using a global function
myDialog(context);
```

But, i think you want to show a error message. So, you can do it with a dialog not an page. It's more efficient because you can specify your dialog box with buttons or messages and you can use this error dialog everywhere. Let's look my global helper function for showing error messages.

```
void showError(BuildContext context, String error) {
  showSnackBar(
    context,
    new Text(
      'Error',
      style: new TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
    ),
    content: new SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new Text(error)
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new FlatButton(
        child: new Text(
          'Ok',
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
      ),
    ]
  );
}

// Using in everywhere
showError(context, 'Sample Error');
```

Comment: @Anilcan I don't think this is going to help with the underlying cause of his problem (which is probably that he is doing this in the constructor of his class rather than the build function). It might tangentially solve it because he rewrites his class that way though, but it would be good to mention something about that.

Comment: btw in your recommended code where is `showSnackBar ` defined ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and I was able to tackle the problem by setting the initial value of the TextFormField by adding the value I need to the controller's text, example:

```
_carPlateController.text = _initValues['carPlate'];
```

or

```
filterController.text = 'search';
```

I hope this helps! As it is an elegant easy solution for when using controllers.