# Dart - Only static members can accessed in initializers

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying with the following code

```
class NewItemCreate extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  NewItemCreateState createState() => new NewItemCreateState();
}

class NewItemCreateState extends State<NewItemCreate>
{

  File _image;
  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
    print(_image.path);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,

        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Report"),
          elevation: 5.0,
        ),
      body:
      Center  (
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              itemImage,
              SizedBox(height: 18.0),
              itemName,
              SizedBox(height: 18.0),
              itemLocation,
              SizedBox(height: 18.0),
              itemLocation,
              SizedBox(height: 18.0),
              itemTime,
              SizedBox(height: 18.0),
              Report,
              SizedBox(height: 38.0),
            ],
          )
      )
    );

  }

  final itemImage =       Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
    child: Material(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      shadowColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.shade100,
      elevation: 5.0,
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: 200.0,
        height: 300.0,
        onPressed: (){
          getImage();
        },
        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        child:
        new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, size: 150.0,color: Colors.blue,),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

There is already a question here, 
[Error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers what does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145150/error-only-static-members-can-be-accessed-in-initializers-what-does-this-mean)
regarding this very issue, but, should I really be using "SingleTickerProviderStateMixin" for this? Also, is this something to do with singletons? (I am still learning programming)

Error after trying out the below answer:
[image]

Comment: What line of above code causes the error?

Comment: getImage() in the final itemImage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
final itemImage = ...
```

initializes a class-level field. This code is executed before the constructor is completed and the object fully initialized, therefore accessing `this.` (implicit or explicit) is forbidden because it can't be guaranteed that what you attempt to access is already initialized.

Creating and caching widgets this way is a bad idea in general anyway.
Instead make it a method:

```
Widget buildItemImage(BuildContext context) => Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
    child: Material(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        shadowColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.shade100,
        elevation: 5.0,
        child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: 200.0,
            height: 300.0,
            onPressed: () {
                getImage();
            },
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            child: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, size: 150.0,color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    ),
);
```

This way the code is first executed when `buildItemImage(context)` is called, not when the object instance is created. At this time it is guaranteed to be save to access `this.`.

Comment: I am still getting error as attached in my original post.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove `final` (replaced with `Widget`)

Comment: Thanks, great explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try to cut the

```
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
child: Material(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
  shadowColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.shade100,
  elevation: 5.0,
  child: MaterialButton(
    minWidth: 200.0,
    height: 300.0,
    onPressed: (){
      getImage();
    },
    color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
    child:
    new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, size: 150.0,color: Colors.blue,),
  ),
),
```

);
And paste it in `children<Widget>[//here]` and add a `new`

```
body:
  Center  (
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
        ------------/*there it is*/---------------------------
          new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
            child: Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              shadowColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.shade100,
              elevation: 5.0,
           child: MaterialButton(
              minWidth: 200.0,
              height: 300.0,
              onPressed: (){
                   getImage();
              },
          color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          child:
          new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, size: 150.0,color: 
                     Colors.blue,),
          ),
        ),
     -----------------------------------------------------
          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          itemName,
          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          itemLocation,
          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          itemLocation,
          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          itemTime,
          SizedBox(height: 18.0),
          Report,
          SizedBox(height: 38.0),
        ],
      )
  )
```

Hope it's work :)

Comment: You have a trailing `);` outside the code block. It would also be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem