# Unable to initialize static member in Dart

Tags: class, flutter, dart, initialization, static-variables

I have read similar questions

1. [Error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers what does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145150/error-only-static-members-can-be-accessed-in-initializers-what-does-this-mean)
2. [Dart - Only static members can accessed in initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682496/dart-only-static-members-can-accessed-in-initializers)

But I am still unable to solve the problem.

I am sending Ip object which has a Ip string from one screen to another.

Here is Second screen's widget and state class in short.

```
class DrawingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Ip ipObj;
//  String ipObj;
  DrawingPage({Key key, @required this.ipObj});
  _DrawingPageState createState() => _DrawingPageState();
}
```

```
class _DrawingPageState extends State<DrawingPage> {

  final String ip = widget.ipObj.ip;     //Error at "widget": Only Static members can be accessed in initializers


}
```

I have tried

1.[Initializer's List](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list).

2.Converting final to static member and then assigning ip value in initState does work.

But the value is set when initState is invoked, but I want to set value before initState.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of options here... I'm not sure which one would be best for your case, but I usually use the second one, as I don't like to reference the 'widget' object in the state all the time:

**Option 1: convert 'ip' to a field**

```
class _DrawingPageState extends State<DrawingPage> {
  String get ip => widget.ipObj.ip;
}
```

**Option 2: pass the ipObj in the constructor of the state:**

```
class DrawingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Ip ipObj;

  DrawingPage({Key key, @required this.ipObj});

 _DrawingPageState createState() => _DrawingPageState(ipObj);
}

class _DrawingPageState extends State<DrawingPage> {

  String ip;

  DrawingPageState(Ip ipObj){
    ip = ipObj.ip;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried both of these methods, but it is still showing the same error, whenever i try to use the string ip in State class.

Comment: Please show the full code. What do you mean by 'try to use the string ip in State class'?

Comment: After using either of the options you mentioned, If I try to print ip in _DrawingPageState it gives me the same error.

Comment: Your solution is correct, I was incorrectly trying to print the value in class body.