# Passing data between pages with bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an app that routes to a "mainapp" page after logging in. This app contains a bottom navigation bar which displays pages of the corresponding pressed icon. I want to pass data of type `Map<String, dynamic>` to these pages but I am having trouble. This map is generated from a function that fetches the data from a server, saves it to shared preferences, then loads the shared preferences and returns it as a map (all contained in `getData()`). I want to pass this map around so I don't have to load shared preferences each time, but will also update this map along with shared preferences when needed( possibly an action on one of the pages).

```
class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {


  Map<String, dynamic> Data;


  StartFunc() async {
   Data = await getData();
   setState(() {}); 
 }


  @override
  void initState() {
    StartFunc();
    super.initState();
  }

  var _pages = [
    PageOne(Data:Data),
    PageTwo(),
    PageThree(),
   PageFour(),
   PageFive(),
  ];

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _currentIndex == 2
        ? PageTwo()
        : Scaffold(
      body: _pages[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.library_books), title: Text('')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), title: Text('')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline), title: Text('')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.mail), title: Text('')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('')),
        ],
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error saying **Only static members can be accessed in initializers**. I was wondering if inherited widgets or other design patterns such as scoped model and BLoC can help but not sure if that's the right way to go. I'm also not sure how I would start implementing them in this case.

Comment: Did you try use `static` in StartFunc() ?

Comment: @RubensMelo I tried making the function static if that's what you meant ```static StartFunc()```, I got an error saying instance members can't be accessed from a static method, it's underlining the setState method and userData variable.

Comment: Yeah if you want to pass data around easily, you're gonna want to use some kind of MVVM pattern such as using ScopedModel, BLoC or creating your own method if these are a bit overkill for simple data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. using an async method in the body of `initState()`
   see [here](https://flutter.institute/run-async-operation-on-widget-creation/) for details
2. using instance data in an initializer
   see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145150/error-only-static-members-can-be-accessed-in-initializers-what-does-this-mean) for details

What follow is a very basic rewrite of your code, with minimal corrections.

The data map is loaded from a mocked backend, updated inside `PageOne` and printed to console in `PageTwo` onTap callback.

Please note that I've changed instance variable `Data` to `data` to be compliant with [Effective Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-other-identifiers-using-lowercamelcase) guidelines.

Note that the gist does not properly addresses the synchronization of the backend service with the shared preferences: this is something that have probably to be accounted in the final product.

I just commented what it is necessary to get your code works:
if the complexity of your system and the relations with external API start growing it could be worth considering a Bloc architecture.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MainApp());

// Mock up of an async backend service
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => {'prop1': 'value1'});
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data;

  PageOne({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: const Text('update preferences'),
        onPressed: () {
          data['prop2'] = 'value2';
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {

  final Map<String, dynamic> data;

  PageTwo({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: const Text('Got It!'),
        onPressed: () {
          print("data is now: [$data]");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  //Map<String, dynamic> Data;
  Map<String, dynamic> data;

  /*
  StartFunc() async {
    Data = await getData();
    setState(() {});
  }
  */

  @override
  void initState() {
    //StartFunc();
    super.initState();
    getData().then((values) {
      setState(() {
        data = values;
      });
    });
  }

  /*
  PageOne(data:data) is an invalid value for an initializer:
   there is no way to access this at this point.
    Initializers are executed before the constructor,
    but this is only allowed to be accessed after the call
    to the super constructor.

  */
  /*
  var _pages = [
    PageOne(data:data),
    PageTwo(),
  ];
  */

 Widget getPage(int index) {
    switch (index){
        case 0:
            return PageOne(data:data);
            break;
        case 1:
            return PageTwo(data:data);
            break;
        default:
            return PageOne();
        break;
    }
  }

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*
    return _currentIndex == 2
        ? PageTwo()
        : Scaffold(

    I use a MaterialApp because of material widgets (RaisedButton)
    It is not mandatory, but it is mainstream in flutter

     */
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("My App Bar")),
          body: getPage(_currentIndex),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.first_page), title: Text('')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.last_page), title: Text('')),
            ],
            onTap: onTabTapped,
            currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer starting from your specific code, I hope it is more useful.

Comment: thank you for your updated answer it was very informing, when I tried printing "data" in the initstate method of PageOne it seemed to be null initially (guess its the same for PageTwo) why isn't "data" there right away, isn't it just passed to PageOne constructor so it's already available?

Comment: It is right: `data` is initially `null` because it will be available when the `Future` in the mocked up async method `getData` will complete (after 1 second). 
When `getData` returned future will complete with a ready value the callback passed to `getData.then()` will be invoked with the value: `data` will be updated (and the widget will be rebuild thanks to `setState`)

Comment: php:   global $var;    30 years passed and the total mess above is the result of humanity decline, I mean we're not even in a different .dart file, it's incredible