# how to transfer data to another tab using bottom tab navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs

I have screens that contains bottom tab navigation, but I get confused when I have to access the data not only in first screen tab but also I need to access in second screen tab, should I declare my `text` using global variable?

```
class BottomTab extends StatefulWidget {
final String text;
BottomTab({this.text});
  @override
  _BottomTabState createState() => _BottomTabState();
}

class _BottomTabState extends State<BottomTab> {
void initState() {
    print(widget.text)
    super.initState();
   }
  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  int _index = 0;

  Widget _myList(int index) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int myindex) => setState(() => _index = myindex),
        currentIndex: index,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _myList(_index),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_index],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54254019/2656632), is it helpful for your situation?

Comment: I tried to understand the code from the link you have given, but I get a question.. so to access my ```text``` in all tabs, is it correct that I need to add this widget ```Widget getPage(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return PageOne(data:data);
    }
    if (index == 1) {
      return PageTwo(data:data);
    }
    // A fallback, in this case just PageOne
    return PageOne();
  }```

Comment: You can provide `getPage(int)` method with your custom logic. If the logic in this answer is suitable for your needs, then use it :)