# Flutter: Where method creates a problem in list

Tags: list, flutter

I use `where method` for filtering a list. But I face a problem.

> Here is my code-

```
class BookData extends ChangeNotifier {


List<MyModel> data = [
    MyModel(name: "Abir", location: "Dhaka"),
    MyModel(name: "Shuvro", location: "Barishal"),
    MyModel(name: "Anik", location: "Barishal")
  ];

 List<MyModel> get getMydata{
   return data;
 }


List<MyModel> myNewList = data.where((item) => item.location == "Barishal").toList(); //Here data. creates this issue




}
```

[image]

***Why is this isuue created ? And  how can I fix this?***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "Only static members can be accessed in initializers" in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615417/how-to-resolve-only-static-members-can-be-accessed-in-initializers-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the list inside a method:

```
class BookData extends ChangeNotifier {


List<MyModel> data = [
    MyModel(name: "Abir", location: "Dhaka"),
    MyModel(name: "Shuvro", location: "Barishal"),
    MyModel(name: "Anik", location: "Barishal")
  ];

 List<MyModel> get getMydata{
   return data;
 }

  void createList(){
   List<MyModel> myNewList = data.where((item) => item.location == "Barishal").toList();   
  }

}
```