# Using argument in initializer list with flutter

Tags: flutter, parameter-passing, initializer

I want to make a data list page. It needs a reference based on user id passed by argument. However, the argument can't be accessed because it is not static.

I tried to pass reference itself by argument. But it also falls into the same problem.

```
class DataViewHome extends StatefulWidget{
    final String userId;

    DataViewHome({this.userId});

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() => DataViewHomeState();
}

class DataViewHomeState extends State<DataViewHome>{
    final dataReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users").child(widget.userId);

    List<String> dataList = new List();
    StreamSubscription<Event> _onDataAddedSubscription;

    DataViewHomeState(){
        _onDataAddedSubscription = dataReference.onChildAdded.listen(_onDataAdded);
    }

    _onDataAdded(Event event){
        setState(() {
            dataList.add(event.snapshot.value);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers what does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145150/error-only-static-members-can-be-accessed-in-initializers-what-does-this-mean)

Comment: you can initialize it in `initState()`