# Flutter : TextEditingController Only Static member can be accessed in initializer error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm passing data from listmosque.dart to update_screen.dart for updating data.
Anything it's work but i want set default value of textedittingcontroller.

```
TextEditingController _txtnrp = TextEditingController(text: "${widget.nrpUpdate}"); <- this error
```

I'm getting message `Only static members can be accessed in initializers.` in `${widget.nrpUpdate}`
How to fix this ?

#### It's my update_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UpdateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String idUpdate;
  final String nrpUpdate;
  final String namaUpdate;
  final String emailUpdate;
  final String jurusanUpdate;
  UpdateScreen(
      {this.idUpdate,
      this.nrpUpdate,
      this.namaUpdate,
      this.emailUpdate,
      this.jurusanUpdate});
  @override
  _UpdateScreenState createState() => _UpdateScreenState();
}

class _UpdateScreenState extends State<UpdateScreen> {
 
 TextEditingController _txtnrp = TextEditingController(text: "${widget.nrpUpdate}"); <- In this line error

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Update ${widget.namaUpdate}'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  
                  controller: _txtnrp,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "NRP"),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50151625/9823185 which is explained in detail

Comment: Yea, answer in bottom solved my problem, thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move it inside `initState`:

```
class _UpdateScreenState extends State<UpdateScreen> {

  TextEditingController _txtnrp;

  @override
  void initState() {
     _txtnrp = TextEditingController(text: "${widget.nrpUpdate}");
     super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: It's work! thank's, Sorry can you tell me why i get the error like that ?

Comment: As it said - `Only static members can be accessed in initializers`. As I know - `widget` isn't initialized yet when you declare fields of `State`. If you need access to widget, or to initialize `AnimationController` - all such things have to be done inside `initState`

Comment: Sure, Thank's sir

Answer (score 0):

Andrey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57430533/1949853) is correct, but just wanted to add some details:

Problem is indeed that you're trying to access `State.widget` before it is initialized, and accessing these parameters through `State.widget` is the recommended way (instead of passing through State constructor).

`build()` method is always called when state changes, so setting controller to `${widget.nrpUpdate}` would actually make the text field behave strangely (resetting it) every time a state changed occured. So, that's another reason why you should set this value inside `initState()` instead. This, eg would clear the text field every time you clicked the button, even though that's not desired:

```
class _UpdateScreenState extends State<UpdateScreen> {
  TextEditingController _txtnrp;
  int _count = 1;

  Widget GetColumn(someText) {
    print(someText);
    return 
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _txtnrp = TextEditingController(text: "${widget.nrpUpdate}");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Update ${widget.namaUpdate}'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(text: someText),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "NRP"),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Click"),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {_count += 1;})
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Other than that, you might want to organize your code when it gets bigger, breaking it into functions and variables. When doing so, you could run into similar "only static objects" errors. One way to avoid this would be:

```
class _UpdateScreenState extends State<UpdateScreen> {

    TextEditingController _txtnrp;

    Widget getColumn(someText)
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(           
            controller: _txtnrp,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "NRP"),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: ...,
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: GetColumn("${widget.nrpUpdate}").                 
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

    @override
    void initState() {
        _txtnrp = TextEditingController(text: "${widget.nrpUpdate}");
        super.initState();
    }
```