# Only static members can be accessed in initializers, error

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I tried to make the `"text"` in the list changeable whith a variable, but I get an error (that´s the dicription from the error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers). I tried to understand a simmilar question, which was also asked on stackoverflow.com ([Error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers what does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145150/error-only-static-members-can-be-accessed-in-initializers-what-does-this-mean)), but I didn´t get it. Could anybody tell me what the problem in my code is? Thanks in advance!

```
var exercisetest = "Hallo";

  var exercises = [
    {"text": exercisetest, "time": 10},
    {"text": exercisetest, "time": 14},
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using exercisetest variable to in exercises and because of that you are getting this error.

If you add **static** keyword then you can use or access that variable as you are doing now.

Like following:

```
static var exercisetest = "Hallo";
```

But static variable will become class variable means that, whatever amount of object you create but all object's will share same variable.

Moreover, you can not access that variable object.exercisetest you can access using class name only classname.exercisetest.

Answer (score 0):

I guessing the example should have been like this:

```
class A {
  String exercisetest = "Hallo";

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> exercises = [
    <String, dynamic>{"text": exercisetest, "time": 10},
    <String, dynamic>{"text": exercisetest, "time": 14},
  ];
}
```

The reason why this does not work is that classes in Dart are not initialized in variable declaration order but rather all fields at the same time when talking about classes.

So the error means that the field `exercisetest` does not have any value or does not exists yet, and therefore you cannot refer to it before the object are done.

This two-step part of object creation can be seen when we define the constructor:

```
class A {
  String exercisetest;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> exercises;

  A() : exercisetest = "Hallo" {
    exercises = [
      <String, dynamic>{"text": exercisetest, "time": 10},
      <String, dynamic>{"text": exercisetest, "time": 14},
    ];
  }
}
```

In this example we define the `exercisetest` before object are done to be created (like you code also do). But if we write something inside `{ }` the object has here been created and we can therefore access e.g. `exercisetest` and use it to define `exercises`.

But since the object are created when we set `exercises` we cannot make `exercises` final since final values must be set before the object are created.