# Only one static member can be accessed in Initilizer

Tags: flutter

Hi Guys am trying to create a search in function my app, which looks for the name for the product that comes from another class who holds all the products title originated from the Firebase DB. However, the ProductData class has a parameter of type DocumentSnapShot. When I declare a varible of type DocumentSnapShot and pass it as a parameter for my class and try to access the title. it gives me the error Only one static member can be accessed in Initilizer. I just do not get why.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flappy_search_bar/flappy_search_bar.dart';
import 'package:jeilaonlinestore/datas/products_data.dart';

class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String>{
  //final DocumentSnapshot snapshot;
 // DocumentSnapshot snapshot = Firestore.instance.collection('products').getDocuments('tshirt');
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot;

  //Get the Doc and Convert it to Product Data.
  String data = ProductData.fromDocument(snapshot).title;
  final cities = [
    'Luanda',
    'Benguela',
    'Huambo',
    'Kuando Kubango',
    'Huila'
  ];
  final recentCities = ['Luanda', 'Benguela'];
  // DataSearch(this.snapshot);

  // get itemBuilder => null;
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildActions
    //Define the Actions for the App Bar
    //The is the Cross that shows in the right corner
    return [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: (){
      //Query should be empty
      query = '';
    })
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildLeading
    //Leading Icon on the Left of the App

    return IconButton(
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
          //We want to provide some Animation into this progress.
          progress: transitionAnimation,
        ),
        onPressed: (){
          //close the search windows
          close(context, null);
          // Navigator.of(context,).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomeTab()));
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildResults
    //Show The Result Based on the Selection.
    //Send it to the product page if the user is logged in otherwise request him to login.
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context)  {

   Future<List> task =  getProductTitle();
    // TODO: implement buildSuggestions
    //Display The Results of the Search
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? recentCities
    //Search Based on what user is input

        : cities.where((searchString) => searchString.startsWith(query)).toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index)=> ListTile(
        onTap: (){
          //This is the Result of the search query
          showResults(context);
        },
        leading: Icon(Icons.location_city),
        //Make your Search highlight for each character that matches your search R.
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: suggestionList[index].substring(0,query.length),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicated question, please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145150/error-only-static-members-can-be-accessed-in-initializers-what-does-this-mean/50151625#50151625

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers what does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145150/error-only-static-members-can-be-accessed-in-initializers-what-does-this-mean)

Comment: Hi Luis, thx for the feedback. Although, am getting the same error however the use case is different. I looked at the link you shared still struggling to figure out where am wrong. I wonder if there is a way by you just looking at the code come up with the solution to fix this error. Thx in advance.